# Why doesn't this AJAX call in Rails work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Under my routes, I have this:

```
POST   /todos(.:format)               todos#create
```

And here is the `create` action:

```
def todo_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name, :done)
end

def create
    @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
    @todo.user = current_user.email
    if @todo.save
        redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was created!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
end
```

Now when I get onto the command line, and try to run this snippet:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/todos",
            data: 'name="Andrew"&done=false'})
```

I receive, `POST http://localhost:3000/todos 400 (Bad Request)`.

Why is this occuring and how can I go about doing this the correct way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST data should be like this:

```
data: "todo[name]=Andrew&todo[done]=false"
```

Comment: Why does this work and not what I have up there? Is it because I have `params.require(:todo)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
url: "/todos.js", # sometimes helps
```

Comment: Do I need to have a todos.js file somewhere? And this yields the same messsage as well. `400, Bad Request`